# Presenting the idea of a PhD research project before publishing it

Tags: phd, paper-submission, presentation

I have an idea for my PhD research project but my supervisor wants me to have that idea/model published or endorsed before I can start working on and she suggested that idea/model to be presented in a conference and have comments about that.

I know about normal papers being presented at conference but what is idea/model presented in the form of paper. Can anyone help me in understanding the format.

Comment: Not very clear situation or question

Comment: I mean to say that traditional papers come with results and discussion but at this stage the research is an idea and wanted to present to get comments about the idea that whether it is good to continue or not. Or if there are any suggestions to incorporate. So in this way, the question is what sections to include in idea pitching paper.

Comment: Then the question was clear but the situation is unclear or at least really unusual. Unless there are workshops at place, or a kind of "summer school". Else of course one can discuss and look for advice, but it should not be the presentation core.

Comment: You are misinterpreting. It is presentation of paper. Not just a presentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a good idea. There are many conferences in which they invite exclusively the Ph.D. students in different domains to a co-located workshop. There the students present their work (so far) and get comments and feedback. Further, there is a chance of getting collaboration by senior researchers.

Have a look at this: https://www.eurosla2019.se/programme/doctoral-student-workshop/

Comment: Good points. The biggest drawbacks are likely to be if it delays things significantly, or is too expensive for the student. If the work can be applied to the eventual research the first is less of a problem. If the prof agrees to help out with conference costs, the second is less of a problem.